# Что за контролы и как самому сделать такие (список с единичным выбором)

Tags: java, android, gui, android-material-dialog-lib, android-dialog

Подскажите, что это за контрол(ы) и как самому сделать то же самое? Это `radio button list`, отображенный в диалоге?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Лично я для таких целей пользую вот эту библиотеку: [Material Dialogs](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs)

В данном конкретном случае с помощью этой библиотеки диалог вызывается так:

```
new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
        .title(R.string.title)
        .items(R.array.items)
        .itemsCallbackSingleChoice(-1, new MaterialDialog.ListCallbackSingleChoice() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSelection(MaterialDialog dialog, View view, int which, CharSequence text) {
                /**
                 * If you use alwaysCallSingleChoiceCallback(), which is discussed below,
                 * returning false here won't allow the newly selected radio button to actually be selected.
                 **/
                return true;
            }
        })
        .positiveText(R.string.choose)
        .show();
```

А выглядит так (см. 2-ой скриншот):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: хотелось бы по-проще, без наворотов и сторонних библиотек.

Comment: Проще некуда) Наворотов тут никаких. Стандартными средствами - больше кода надо. Если не пользовать библиотеки, то можете столкнуться с проблемой различного отображения диалогов на разных версиях API. Имею в виду стили диалогов. Эта же либа на всех API отображает диалоги одинаково.

Comment: что используется в гугловских приложениях, она или нет?

Comment: Не стоит слепо ориентироваться на гугловые приожения... Они не всегда следуют своим же гайдлайнам и часто советуют делать такие штуки делать, для коих стандартных инструментов нет. Взять тот же материал дизайн - представили давно, а либу "дизайн" выпустили вот только что. И она глючная. Так что порой сторонние либы - лучшее решение. Тем более что предложенная - популярна и развивается.

Answer (score 4):

Вам обязательно с разделительной полосой? Если нет, то используете RadioGroup и пихаете туда сколько нужно RadioButton. Если принципиально с подчёркиванием, то придётся реализовывать отдельную логику проверки нажатой RadioButton, чтобы нельзя было нажать другую, но я советую использовать RadioGroup, он по дефолту поддерживает выбор одного единственного из множества, просто не будет разделителей, да и без них это бы выглядело куда лучше

Comment: необязательно с полосой, но обязательно, чтобы можно было выбрать только одну radio button. А что за диалог, где его найти, как вызвать, как вернуть значение?

Comment: Скорее всего fragmentdialog. Погуглите про него,  а то с телефона долго