# AndroidStudio подчёркивает this при попытке открыть MaterialDialog в OnClick

Tags: java, android, activity, android-material-dialog-lib

В чем ошибка (this) в коде

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                .title(R.string.app_name)
                .show();
    }
});
```

скрин:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: небыло времини извините

Comment: Времени поисследовать собственную проблему у вас, видимо, тоже не было? Э-эх... Хотите совет? Смените цветовую схему для начала, эта скушала кусок сообщения об ошибке. Или это просто форматирование ошибок такое странное? ._.

Comment: да вроде все на месте, ясно видно, что конструктор хочет `Context`, а ему подсовывают анонимный класс на базе `View.OnClickListener`.

Comment: @zRrr , как исправить?

Comment: @D-side, какое уже есть... есле чесно небыло времини ... + я плохо шарю в етом

Comment: Если у вас нет времени написать хороший вопрос, думаю, вам не стоит рассчитывать на то, что у нас найдётся время написать хороший ответ.

Comment: @VladD , с вами полностью согласен... можете не отвечать.. извините

Comment: Всем заминусившим - смените гнев на милость, ибо я исправил вопрос и он теперь конфетка.

Comment: А вот похожий вопрос по этой либе и фрагментам: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461649/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-material-dialog-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5

Comment: А вот отсюда пошди эти вопросы на ru-SO: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/461088/17609

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, как всгда на высоте)))

Comment: Метки (теги) нужны для того, чтобы выделить основные моменты ВОПРОСА, по которым другие пользователи быстрее смогут найти решение аналогичной проблемы, а не для демонстрации собственных предпочтений в выборе IDE. Вопрос никак не связан с проблемами при работе IDE Android Studio и этот тег в вопросе не нужен.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`MaterialDialog` `Builder` [на входе принимает Context](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/afollestad/materialdialogs/MaterialDialog.java#L476).

У вас же `this` - ссылка на анонимный класс `OnClickListener`.

Можно например так:

```
new MaterialDialog.Builder(НазваниеВашегоActivity.this){...}
```

Comment: как исправить???

Comment: @Андрей передать экземпляр `Context`, очевидно.

Comment: @D-side , что именно и где изменить я полный 0((((

Comment: @Андрей `new MaterialDialog.Builder(НазваниеВашегоActivity.this){...}`